# Argparser flag with no argument with precedence

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I have couple of positional and optional arguments (using argparser) , now need to add a flag which takes no argument/values and essentially calls a method.

let's say this is the current parser :

```
./run.py arg1 arg2 -i input
```

here's the brief sample code

```
parser.add_argument("arg1",
                    help="arg1 handler")
parser.add_argument("arg2",
                    help="arg2 handler")
parser.add_argument('-i', dest='input_handler',
                    help="input handler")
```

what I'm looking for is something similar when you use `--help` which results in showing the help (and **takes precedences on other flags**).
So I want to support a special flag (like --help) without worrying about providing all the other flags in the command line.

So something like this should work as well:

```
./run.py --list
```

I was thinking to use `'store_true'` to take the flag with no value, but it does not have the precedence over other flags.

any comments/suggestions is really appreciated

Comment: Could be useful if you also shared some code. That might help people to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why do you need precedence? You can parse your arguments and then check if `--list` is there before acting on your other arguments.

Comment: I want `./run.py --list` to work. Similar to `./run --help` which does not required any other flags/arguments. If I don't provide all the other arguments, argparser complains about missing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use soemthing like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--list',action='store_true',help='perform some task')
parser.add_argument('--input',type=str, required=False, help='input variable')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.list:
    perform_function()
elif args.input is not None:
    function(args.input)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) field.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Runs using two args and an option input

Usage: ./run.py arg1 arg2 -i input

Arguments:
    arg1/arg2: any order

Options:
   -i input
"""
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=__doc__)
parser.add_argument("pos_args", help="Unknown pos args sequence", nargs=2)  # '+' for any number of args
parser.add_argument('-i', dest='input_handler', help="input handler")

args = parser.parse_args()

arg1, arg2 = args.pos_args
```

Comment: Did you actually try this?  `nargs="2"` probably raises some sort of error, either on creation, parsing, or displaying a help.

Comment: Fixed: don't use quotes where it's expecting an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`-h` help takes precedence because it forces sys.exit when encountered.  That is, it has a Action class that prints the help and then exits.

There is a `version` action class that does something similar - display a message and exit.

All other actions store something in the `args` Namespace, and continue parsing.  The `missing arguments` complaint is produced at the end of parsing when it deduces that some positional (or other required) arguments have not been filled.

I can think of several solutions:

- define a new Action subclass modeled on `help` or `version`.  If you take this route, you should do the development, so you know exactly what is happening.
- change your positionals to something that is optional.  `nargs='?'` is a possibility, but making flagged is better.  In this case `input_handler` could be a simple `store_true` action.
- use subparsers.  `input_handler` would be parser that takes no arguments.  The othe subparser would take the 2 positionals.  Look at the subparsers documentation, and the `set_defaults` note.